# My old roommate stole my iPhone and i just got it back

Tags: iphone, ios, security, password

They changed the passcode and now I can't get in. After upgrading to the iPhone 12, my old roommate stole my old iPhone 11. They changed the passcode, but continued to use my Apple ID and password. I have since gotten the iPhone 11 back but cannot get into it because I don't know the passcode they used. Is there anyway to access my old phone without deleting everything they had on it? I'm hoping to retain the proof that they were accessing my account I eat my bank, PayPal, etc..

Comment: It would defeat the purpose if you could get access to the device *without* a passcode. And even if you can get access somehow, how does this help you prove anything?

Comment: It's attached to your AppleID, don't you have it in Find My?  Remote lock it and wipe it.  You need to look at this from a security perspective.  How do we (or Apple) know that you're the actual owner and not the nefarious roommate trying to bypass a security lock?  Use the tools Apple provides and secure your device.